# How can I push template args to an Array

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

#### How can I push template args to array?

> I want to make this function below returns
> array of ints values from template args

```
template <int... args>
int* data(... args)
{
    int* m_data = // push template args to array
}
```

Comment: Are you dead set on using a `C` style array? How about a `std::vector`?

Comment: I'm trying to create something like std::vector and that's for the constructor of the class

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the array within the `data` function? Or, has it already been created prior to the call of the `data` function?

Comment: `data(... args)` won't compile. It's unclear whether you want to pass the values as template arguments, or as "normal" function arguments. How is `data` supposed to be called?

Comment: this is just an example I want to know how to push template args to an array

Comment: then how to do it I have no idea how template args work

Comment: It supposes to be called like data(1, 2, 3, 4) then it makes an array from the args then return m_Data

Comment: sry for my bad english btw

Comment: `data(1, 2, 3, 4)` doesn't involve template arguments. The question is still unclear to me.

Comment: If you really want template arguments, template arguments are passed inside `<...>` so it would be called as `data<1,2,3>()` and the line could be something like `int* m_data = new int[sizeof...(args)]{ args... };`. This is a highly unorthodox style, though. Maybe it's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to dynamically allocate an `array` and populate the elements of the array during construction.

### Dynamic Array

```
template<typename ...Args>
static int* data( Args&& ...args ) 
{
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...( Args );
    int* a1{ new int[ size ]{ std::forward<Args>( args )... } };
    return a1;
}

int main( ) 
{
    int* ptr{ data( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ) };
    delete[ ] ptr;
}
```

### Static Array

```
template<typename ...Args>
static int* data( Args&& ...args ) 
{
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...( Args );
    static int a1[ size ]{ std::forward<Args>( args )... };
    return a1;
}

int main( ) 
{
    int* ptr{ data( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ) };
    
}
```

### Populating the array after construction

```
template<typename ...Args>
static int* data( Args&& ...args ) 
{
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...( Args );

    // Use can also use a static array here instead.
    int* a1{ new int[ size ] };

    std::size_t count{ 0 };
    for ( auto value : { std::forward<Args>( args )... } )
    {
        a1[ count++ ] = value;
    }

    return a1;
}

int main( ) 
{
    int* ptr{ data( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ) };
    delete[ ] ptr;
}
```

### Asserting all values are of type int

```
template<typename ...Args>
static int* data( Args&& ...args ) 
{
    static_assert( std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<int, Args>...>, 
        "All args must be of type 'int'" );

    constexpr auto size = sizeof...( Args );
    int* a1{ new int[ size ]{ std::forward<Args>( args )... } };
    return a1;
}

int main( ) 
{
    int* ptr{ data( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.0 ) };
    delete[ ] ptr;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to make it dynamically allocated. Just make a static array and return that.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not sure what his use case is, which is why I went with a dynamic array. I'll show both.

Comment: what if I want to make the args with a specific type like int for example

Comment: @SobhyRzk Edited the answer to show how to use a `static_assert` to verify all values are of type `int`.

Comment: @SobhyRzk If my answer helped you, please make sure to accept it.